# reversemp usage in geometry package

Tags: geometry

When I set my geometry like displayed below, the ''test test test' tekst is displayed at the reverse marginpart, however the showframe doesnt adjust correctly.

I tried this simple code for a more complex document. When I use this same method with for instance images, overfull \hbox errors occur, which made me think the reversemp isnt working correctly.

Does somebody know how to correctly set the geometry in such a way that for my single side document the margin part is displayed on the left side for all pages and also shown by the showframe???

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
        includemp,
        showframe,
        reversemp,
        paperwidth=20.10cm,
        paperheight=25.80cm,
        top=2.30cm,
        bottom=3.4cm,
        inner=2.7cm,
        outer=2.7cm,
        marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
        marginparsep=0.4cm
        ]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\marginpar{test test test}

\end{document}
```

[image: showframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geometry` doesn't support this. But it can draw the lines on both sides, if the option `twoside` is given. Looking into the code reveals, that the internal macros `\Gm@vrules@mpi` and `\Gm@vrules@mpii` are used to draw the vertical lines. The first for right marginpars the second for left ones. By adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother
```

to the preamble, `geometry` can be persuaded to draw the marginpar on the left.

Note: this is a hack, which may cease to work with future versions of `geometry`. And with it the lines for marginpars are now only draw on the left, even with the option `twoside`.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
        includemp,
        showframe,
        reversemp,
        paperwidth=20.10cm,
        paperheight=25.80cm,
        top=2.30cm,
        bottom=3.4cm,
        inner=2.7cm,
        outer=2.7cm,
        marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
        marginparsep=0.4cm
        ]{geometry}

% added
\makeatletter
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\marginpar{test test test}

\end{document}
```